# Python subprocess.check_call - exit status 48

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, osx-yosemite

I am trying to run `subprocess.check_call` in python, but keep getting `exit status 48`. This command works correctly via Terminal in OSX and exit status is 0:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/Python/ChannelAssign /Volumes/GRAID/_PREVIEWS/MASTER.mov
```

But this keeps giving me `exit status 48`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['/Users/me/Desktop/Python/ChannelAssign', '/Volumes/GRAID/_PREVIEWS/MASTER.mov'])
```

This gives me:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/me/Desktop/Python/ChannelAssign', '/Volumes/GRAID/_PREVIEWS/MASTER.mov']' returned non-zero exit status 48
```

Comment: Try `echo $?` after running the command in the Terminal. Is the output `48` by any chance?

Comment: No, the output is `0`.

Comment: Does `subprocess.check_call("/Users/me/Desktop/Python/ChannelAssign /Volumes/GRAID/_PREVIEWS/MASTER.mov", shell=True)` work?

Comment: This gives exactly the same result, `exit status 48`.

Comment: are you running the python script via Terminal?